# Set path for my images folder with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, path

Can someone help me with my school project? I wanted to use an animated slideshow from codepen.io, and it's really good looking, but so far I worked only with HTML and CSS, so I don't know much about JavaScript. I wanted to put images from my images folder to the slideshow.

My images are located in Project/images folder, and my index.html is located in Projects folder.
How do I set a path to my images in JavaScript?
Here's an example of JavaScript code for the slideshow:

```
var slide = new Slide(width, height, 'out');
var l1 = new THREE.ImageLoader();
l1.setCrossOrigin('Anonymous');
l1.load('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/175711/winter.jpg', function(img) {
  slide.setImage(img);
})
root.scene.add(slide);
```

Comment: `l1.load("images/yourimagenamehere.jpg")`?

Comment: Please post project hierarchy because you need to use a relative link by the looks of it.

Answer (score -1):

If this is your project hierarchy

```
Project
--Images
  --image1.jpg
  --image2.jpg
  --image3.jpg
--index.html
--style.css
--main.js
```

(accessing from 'main.js')
You would do

```
l1.load("Images/image1.jpg", function(img) {
  // Insert Code here
});
```

Comment: Hello Marvin, tnx for answering my question. Unfortunately, I tried it that way, but it won't load my local images, browser doesn't even load the images from url that author of the script provided, it shows only black canvas with transition effect. Is there any other way to set image source for l1 variable? https://codepen.io/zadvorsky/pen/PNXbGo this is the link of the source code.

Comment: Please post your project hierarchy and when you use what I gave you what it prints to the console